# Which website of Stack Exchange should I post this question on?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

If I had a problem repairing a domestic appliance, which website of Stack Exchange should I post the question on?

Comment: Appliance such as Raspberry Pi, fridge, game console, robot butler, car engine, what?

Comment: @random `domestic appliance` = fridge,AC, washing machine, fan, mixer, grinder, radio, TV, bread toaster.

Comment: :) this seems a dumb question, Actually my rice cooker is broken. seems I enter a wrong place again. :D

Comment: Why don't you go to the sellers website? :D

Comment: :) You know.SO is becaming part of my life. If there is any question, Firstly I would think about "Maybe I should ask it in SO."

Comment: @random I read that as "robot butter." I was a bit terrified to ask.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure a suitable SE site is available. According to the [help page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at Home Improvement / DIY the  following is listed as being welcome:

> Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances.

I'm not active on that site but I think describing a rice cooker as a major appliance would be pushing your luck. On [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) where I am active the following is a close reason:

> Questions on appliance repair are off-topic unless they involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired. See: [Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic)

So it would really only be welcome if you had basic test gear and a reasonable knowledge of electronics so you could somewhat isolate the problem to begin with. You'd also likely need a circuit diagram (either from a service guide or reverse-engineered yourself) to get any reasonable sort of answer other than just a broad range of guesses or obvious advice like checking the fuse.